# Maven: share sources between projects

Tags: java, maven

I have two projects which are child of a common parent project. There is also a generator project and a corresponding maven plugin project for the generator. Also, both child projects are using the same input file, which is used for the code generation:

```
parent: pom
  child1: jar
    src/main/generator/input.gen
  child2: jar
    src/main/generator/input.gen
  generator: jar
  generator-plugin: maven-plugin
```

The generator plugin is an in-house made Maven plugin:

```
@Mojo(name = "generate", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.GENERATE_SOURCES, threadSafe = true)
public class GeneratorPlugin extends AbstractMojo {
    @Parameter(required = true, readonly = true, defaultValue = "${project}")
    private MavenProject project;
    @Parameter(required = true, defaultValue = "${project.basedir}/src/main/generator/input.gen")
    private File         input;

   ...
```

}

Currenlty, this `input.gen` is duplicated in `src/main/generator/input.gen` of both `child1` and `child2`. This is a problem. I would like to have just one version of `input.gen`.

How should I structure my projects and how should I refer to this shared copy in `<configuration><input>...</input></configuration>` for the `generator-plugin` plugin in the pom of the two child projects?

Comment: First follow the conventions and never generate resources etc. into `src`   cause `src` is checked in into version control which means every time you run your plugin the source code is changed. The best location is to generate things into `target` directory which is by default ignored by version control. Furthermore a resources which is generated is packaged into the resulting jar file where the resource can be accessed by the classpath also by other modules.

Comment: @khmarbaise I think there is a misunderstanding or confusion. The `input.gen` is an input resource, it contains the definitions of the schema, models, ...for which classes must be generated by the generator. In other words, it is not generated resources.

Comment: Ah now I got it Sorry misunderstanding on my site. But this means you should have only a single module which contains the `input.gen` and the appropriate plugin which generates from this file the classes. As a result you will get a jar file which you can be reused from other modules...without duplicating anything...

Comment: @khmarbaise In my example, both `child1` and `child2` use the same input file. However, `child1` generates something else than `child2`. You can view `child1` as the backend component and `child2` the client component, to have a real-life example. That's why I asked to have `input.gen` shared between the two projects without duplicating it. Hopefully it is more clear now ;).

Comment: Make a package which contains only the `input.get` in `src/main/resources` and load the file via classloader other childs can use it as dependency...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Maven Remote Resources Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-remote-resources-plugin/) might be what you're looking for.

Here is an [example](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-remote-resources-plugin/examples/sharing-resources.html).

Comment: Thank you. I will try it out and let you know!

Answer (score 0):

My take would be (not tested):

- Put `input.gen` into a shared dependency in `src/main/resources`
- Modify the generator to accept classpath resources as input instead / in addition to files
- Add the shared dependency with `input.gen` as `provided` scope to prevent it from ending up in the final product

Comment: Could you please elaborate how the second step can be done?

Comment: E.g. take input path as `String` then do `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` to get associated `InputStream`.

Comment: Thanks, clever idea. Though, I prefer the other proposal as this is a dedicated plugin for such problems.