# Maven - maven-remote-resources-plugin not including all resource directories

Tags: java, maven, maven-resources-plugin, maven-remote-resources

I have a project with multiple resource directories:

```
src/main/resources
src/main/generator
src/main/generator2
```

I declare these resource directories as following:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/generator</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/generator2</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    ....
</build>
```

I am using `maven-remote-resources-plugin` to make these resources available in other projects. I am using this plugin as following:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/generator</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/generator2</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>bundle</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

After building, all resources from all three resource directories are in the JAR. That's great. However, `remote-resources.xml` only contains the resources from `src/main/resources`. How can I fix this?

I tried playing around with the `resourcesDirectory` configuration property, but it seems I can only set one resource directory? I could set this property as following, but this seems like an ugly hack:

```
<configuration>
    <resourcesDirectory>${basedir}/src/main</resourcesDirectory>
    <includes>
        <include>**/*</include>
    </includes>
</configuration>
```

Comment: First what kind of resources do you need in another project?

Comment: As I already mentioned in the other question it looks you are going the wrong path...

Comment: @khmarbaise I tried to answer this in my comment in the other ticket: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46133900/maven-share-sources-between-projects

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure, but you could try either something like:

```
<configuration>
    <resourcesDirectory>${basedir}/src/main</resourcesDirectory>
    <includes>
        <include>resources/**/*</include>
        <include>generator/**/*</include>
        <include>generator2/**/*</include>
    </includes>
</configuration>
```

or try different executions:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>bundle-resources</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>bundle</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>bundle-generator</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>bundle</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <resourcesDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/generator</resourcesDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>bundle-generator2</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>bundle</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <resourcesDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/generator2</resourcesDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

but I'm not sure if remote-resources.xml will be merged or overwritten.

You could also try to execute the plugin in a [later phase](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) on the output directory (prepare-package to be safe, but process-sources might work as well as I think resources:resources will be executed first):

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>bundle-resources</id>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>bundle</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <resourcesDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</resourcesDirectory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>file1</include>
                        <include>file2</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: I will try these things out and let you know!